# Duplicate cells

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

How can I eliminate duplicate data in excel without aggregating them all (keeping the first data and eliminating the rest)?
Example column A:

Line 1: John

Line 2: John

Line 3: John

Line 4: Philip

Line 5: Philip

Line 6: Tim

Line 7: Tim

Line 8: Tim

How can I get just the lines 1,4 and 6, and the rest with blank cells?

So that it looks like this:

Line 1: John

Line 2:

Line 3:

Line 4: Philip

Line 5:

Line 6: Tim

Line 7:

Line 8:

Is it possible also by vba code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Group Duplicates

- For the range `A1:ALastRow`, it is 'mimicking' copying the formula `=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)` e.g. into the range `B2:BLastRow`, copying the values to the range `A2:ALastRow` and then clearing the range `B2:BLastRow`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveGroupDuplicates()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("IF(" & .Address & "=" _
                & .Offset(-1).Address & ",""""," & .Address & ")")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @vbasic2008 ! However, now I have this: 

Line 1: John

Line 2:0

Line 3:

Line 4: Philip

Line 5: 0

Line 6: Tim

Line 7: 0

Line 8:

That is, in the cell just below the customer, 0 appears and in the remaining cells, the cell appears blank

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the code. It works fine for numbers or strings on my end. Maybe try the code in a new workbook to come to a conclusion.

Comment: Now have a table with the subtotals created based on the excel menu (data->subtotal). Now I'd like to paint the cells gray and make the lines that say subtotal bold. Is it possible with vba code? Thanks @vbasic2008

Answer (score 0):

You could enter the following formula in column B and then paste the result as values over the original data:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1,A1,"")
```

Enter this into B1 and fill it down.